# Using Google Analytics, how can I find the 10 pages with the biggest traffic changes in the last 30 days?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic

I am looking to find top 10 posts which has gain traffic, lost traffic etc.

Comment: See this post https://plus.google.com/+avinash/posts/GKSmS4NaarS

Answer (score 1):

If by top 10 posts you refer to most visited pages, once you have opened the view for your website under the Reporting tab:

1. Set the date range (in the upper right corner) to Last 30 days
2. Go to Behavior > Site Content > All pages to get a breakdown of the most popular pages by default metrics.
3. To filter out only blog posts, go to the search bar (just bellow the graph on the right side) and type /blog or /blog-post or the part of the URL category that your site uses for blog posts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is useful information, but it sounds like they want to see changes in traffic (gain and loss) rather than most popular pages.

Comment: Exactly, which pages has gain traffic over 30 days and which have lost, so that one can find out what is working and what is not. Anyway thanks for information.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I have missed that part. OK then, after taking the above mentioned steps, I would nclick the "Comparison" data view (located just on the right of the search box, 4th icon) and compare Pageviews or Unique Pageviews with the site average to get a sense of the performance of the pages/posts. Another option is to go back to the first step and compare the last 30 days with the previous 30 days, then go through the same steps to get a better view of the performance of the pages.